# pyautogui.pixel NameError: name 'Image' is not defined

Tags: python, pyautogui

so, I was following a tutorial and noticed that NameError: name 'Image' is not defined, I checked the pinned comment and it said it only worked with python 3.7.3, I downloaded that version yet I still have the same issues as before with 3.10.6
[Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0zsYh.png)
[Error in terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eg4Ox.png)

I tried downgrading python 3.10.6 - 3.7.3

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The `pyscreeze` library specifically ignores all import errors, so if it tries to import the `Image` name from `PIL` and that fails, there will be no error:

https://github.com/asweigart/pyscreeze/blob/master/pyscreeze/__init__.py#L18

So, you need to make sure that PIL is available, by installing `Pillow`: https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/installation.html

Comment: I need 15 points or whatever to like this post, seriously I didnt think it was this simple . Thanks a lot dude!!!

Comment: @New_Dev no problem. Next time, just check the description on PyPi - it says right there `Screenshot functionality requires the Pillow module.`. Usually requirements like that are listed in the installation instructions or readme of python packages.